# Capture and pass data into textfields

Tags: java, android-studio, ocr

I'm currently developing an Optical Character Recognition(OCR) apps which will pass the recognized data from the business card into the contact.I already managed to [recognized the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcT1S.png) from the business card.

The question is how to recognized the things such as **phone number** in that text box and pass it into the [phone contact textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJg3c.png) ?

Comment: Can you show us how the text looks like?

Comment: the recognized text looks like the image in "recognized the data" link above.60192699337 is the phone number from the text box so i would like the program to recognized that phone number and pass it into the textfield in my contact database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String text  = "This is the text 2432423 which contains phone numbers 56565555";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{5,12}"); // at least 5 at most 12
// before match remove all the spaces, to ensure the length on numbers is OK it will work more better. 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text.replaceAll(" ", ""));
while (matcher.find()) {
    String num = matcher.group();
    System.out.println("phone = " + num);
}
```

And this the output:

```
phone = 2432423
phone = 56565555
```

**Note:** The at least and at most, you can change as your requirement.

Comment: would you give me your email please?

Comment: Yes. bahram_120@hotmail.com

Comment: okay i already email you regarding this matter.hope you can help

Comment: OK I will check it, and will send you the reply.